# Using binary operator in lazyeval call with rlang

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation, rlang, standard-evaluation

Let's say I want to add 1 to every value of a column using `dplyr` and standard evaluation.

I can do :

```
library(dplyr)
data <- head(iris)
var <- "Sepal.Length"
mutate(data, !!rlang::sym(var) := !!quo(`+`(!!rlang::sym(var), 1)))
```

But what if I would like to use `+` as binary operator and not as function ?
I can't figure out how to write the `+` with a symbol in a quosure.
In most of my attempts I got an error for trying to use a non-numeric argument (the symbol for example) with the binary operator `+`.

With the deprecated `mutate_` you can use `lazyeval::interp` which allowed you to do it easily :

```
mutate_(data, .dots = setNames(list(lazyeval::interp(~var + 1, var = as.symbol(var))), var))
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use

```
mutate(data, !!rlang::sym(var) := (!!rlang::sym(var)) + 1)
```

Note the parenthesis around the bang-bang part. This is only necessary because you are probably using an older version of rlang. In older versions (<0.2) the `!!` has a very low precedence so the addition happens before the expansion. Starting with rlang 0.2 the `!!` has been given a different operator precedence and works more how you might expect.

Of course if you are applyting the same transformation to a bunch of columns, you might want to use the `mutate_at`, `mutate_all`, or `mutate_if` versions, which also allow the transformations to be specific with the formula syntax.

```
mutate_if(data, is.numeric, ~.x+1)
mutate_all(data, ~.x+1)
mutate_at(data, var, ~.x+1)
```

Comment: Thank you ! I didnt know that the wrapping `!!quo()` was useless and indeed I'm using rlang v0.1.6